# Change color of plots in pgfplots globally

Tags: pgfplots

In pgfplots I can change the color of plots locally as in the example below. However is there a way to change the color for all plots in a document globally?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}
      \addplot[color=red] coordinates{(0,0) (1,2)};
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A good approach is to define your own "cycle list".

The cycle list controls which colors are assigned unless your explicitly overrule the cycle list:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    cycle list={red\\yellow\\green\\},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}
      \addplot coordinates{(0,0) (1,2)};
      \addplot coordinates{(0,1) (1,3)};
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here, the first plot has no arguments and uses the first entry of the current `cycle list` (which is `red`). The second plot uses the second entry of the `cycle list` (which is `yellow`).

This allows to define a global *set* of colors.

If the global `cycle list` contains only one entry, all plots will use this entry.

At the same time, you can still overrule color definitions by writing `\addplot[<customized>]` (which will ignore the cycle list entry) or `\addplot+[<customized>]` which will still use the cycle list, but it will append the customized options.

Answer (score 11):

**EDIT:**

The following comment of Christian Feuersänger must regard

> The solution is correct - but every axis plot post will append the
>   options to every single plot. In case you want one plot to be (say)
>   green, you would need to clear every axis plot post first

You can set this via `every axis plot post`

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
 every axis plot post/.append style={red,mark=none}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}
      \addplot coordinates{(0,0) (1,2)};
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the [pgfplots manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) at page 236 you will find more settings. For example `every axis plot no`

[image]

Comment: The solution is correct - but `every axis plot post` will append the options to every single plot. In case you want one plot to be (say) green, you would need to clear `every axis plot post` first.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger: Thanks for the information.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger: I used your comment ;-)