# Default curve style in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

Can I set a default style for curves in pgfplots? E.g. I want all my curves in my document to be blue, axes black.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the answers here: [Change color of plots in pgfplots globally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39555/change-color-of-plots-in-pgfplots-globally)

You can set the style globally using `pgfplotsset`, in your case something like `\pgfplotsset{every axis plot post/.append style={blue,mark=none}}`.

Example with blue curves and black axes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{every axis plot post/.append style={blue,mark=none}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [domain=-1:1]{x^2};
\addplot [domain=-1:1] {sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Example result]