# Changing plot colors

Tags: pgfplots

I want to change the color of my plot, so I do as written [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39555/change-color-of-plots-in-pgfplots-globally), but nothing changed.

Btw, can you help me to understand why is my colum from 2009 not plotting?
Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz} 
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
    \usetikzlibrary{chains}
    \usetikzlibrary{trees}
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{8,108,131}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 


\pgfplotsset{
    cycle list={mycolor\\gray},
}
\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            x tick label style={
                /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
            ylabel=Time,
            legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},
            anchor=north,legend columns=1},
            ybar interval=0.7,
            xlabel=Requêtes
        ]
        \addplot 
            coordinates {(2012,1900) (2011,1500)
                 (2010,1746) (2009,1534)};%o0ur
        \addplot 
            coordinates {(2012,1043) (2011,947) 
                (2010,1550) (2009,1398)};%them
        \legend{Request,Request b}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And here is the output:
[image: Out from code above]

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a couple of positions the syntax was not quite what it should be. Try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{8,108,131}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 


\pgfplotsset{ /pgfplots/bar cycle list/.style={/pgfplots/cycle list={
{mycolor,fill=mycolor!30!white,mark=none},
{gray,fill=gray!30!white,mark=none},
{brown!60!black,fill=brown!30!white,mark=none},
{black,fill=gray,mark=none},
}, },
}



\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            x tick label style={
                /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
            ylabel=Time,
            legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},
            anchor=north,legend columns=1},
            %ybar interval=0.7, 
            ybar=5pt,
            xtick={2009,...,2012},
            xlabel=Requ\^{e}tes
        ]
        \addplot 
            coordinates {
            (2012,1900) (2011,1500)
                 (2010,1746) (2009,1534) };%o0ur
        \addplot 
            coordinates { 
            (2012,1043) (2011,947) 
                (2010,1550) (2009,1398) };%them
        \legend{Request,Request b}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]